# C# Compiled to CIL

Tags: c#

I understand that the following C# code:

```
var evens = from n in nums where n % 2  == 0 select n;
```

compiles to:

```
var evens = nums.Where(n => n % 2 == 0);
```

But what does it mean that it compiles to that? I was under the impression that C# code compiles directly into CIL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood something. The query expression:

```
var evens = from n in nums where n % 2 == 0 select n;
```

doesn't *compile* to:

```
var evens = nums.Where(n => n % 2 == 0);
```

Rather, the two lines of code compile directly to CIL. It just so happens that they compile to (effectively) identical CIL. The compiler may convert the query to an intermediate form in the process of analyzing the query code, but the ultimate result is, of course, CIL.

Comment: But in Bart De Smet's book "C# 4.0 Unleashed", on page 921 he says:
"and indeed, it gets compiled into the former syntax".
He explicitly states that the first one gets compiled into the second one.

Comment: @user2063755: It may be a mistake in terminology.  It's my understand (which may also be flawed, of course) that the former gets translated into the latter as a pre-compilation step.  So, as part of the compile process, the former becomes the latter and then the whole thing is compiled into CIL.

Comment: So does that mean anything that is "syntactic sugar" will be converted into the "longer" form of the code as part of a pre compile process?
So the using statement would also be converted to the code which uses .Dispose()?

Comment: @user2063755 Yes, that's pretty much it. I'd say the author's statement seems to be a 'slip of the pen'.

Comment: Is there any documentation on this pre compilation process? (just out of curiosity).

Comment: @user2063755: doubtful, as the internals of the compiler are undocumented outside of Microsoft. Some of the people who worked on it, such as Eric Lippert (who posts on this site) may have blog posts about it if you search hard enough.

Comment: If you grab the book "Linq in Action" it goes into detail on how the query syntax gets transformed into the actual method calls. For Linq specifically this is well defined; it has to be for other people to write Linq providers. It doesn't involve details of the compiler internals, just the conventions that cover the specific Linq syntax.

Comment: Also, don't get hung up on the word "compile". Bart is a compiler guy, and probably uses the term "compile" whenever some source text is transformed into another form. The result of a "compile" doesn't have to be anything in particular, it just needs to be something different.

Answer (score 1):

This is a C#/LINQ expression:

`var evens = from n in nums where n % 2  == 0 select n;`

This is a C# lambda expression:

`var evens = nums.Where(n => % 2 == 0);`

They are *both* C#, and they *both* get compiled into CIL.

You can read more about lambdas here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx
- http://www.dotnetperls.com/where

You can read more about LINQ here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx

The two expressions are equivalent.

One does *NOT* get "compiled" into the other.  Honest :)

Comment: I understand that they both (eventually) get compiled into the same CIL, but the author of the book I'm reading says that one gets compiled into the other (I assume he means before the compilation to CIL), I want to find out if this is true or not, or if the author made a mistake and meant that they would both get compiled to the same CIL.

Comment: Strictly speaking, either you're misinterpreting what he said ... or he misspoke himself.  HOWEVER ... [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) *doe*s depend on .Net [lambdas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx).  Perhaps that's the point he was trying to make.  IMHO...

Comment: SUGGESTION: familiarize yourself with Ildasm (it's free from Microsoft) and familiarize yourself with how different C# code is translated to CIL.  Here are a couple of tutorials: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387%28v=vs.71%29.aspx, http://www.rapidprogramming.com/tutorial/How-to-Use-ILDASM--450.  Have fun!

Comment: I think you should edit your answer to mention that they both get compiled to CIL however there is an intermediate step for var evens = from n in nums where n % 2 == 0 select n;, whereas var evens = nums.Where(n => % 2 == 0); is directly compiled to CIL.

Comment: I'm still not sure you're clear about this.  There *IS NO* specific "intermediate step".  At the same time, there are *many* "intermediate steps" for most compilers and most optimizers.  The important thing is to understand that neither is expression is "compiled into" the other in terms of IL bytecode.  And that, further down the line, IL itself is "compiled" to machine code.  And the distinction between "C#" and "LINQ".  IMHO...